# Is there a way to capture error message in chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

Hi I need to grep error message from chrome console such as 404 file not found, not sure what api chrome is calling to throw error, but seems not `console.error`.
I've tried to override `console.error`, but it doesn't work.

```
//this would not work for error thrown by browser.
console.error=function(msg){
    alert(msg);
}
```

ps. Not limited to using javascript.

Comment: If these helps, [javascript-error-notifier](https://code.google.com/p/javascript-error-notifier/) and [Debugging JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging?csw=1#js_exceptions).

Comment: @Sheikh, thanks, it works for normal javascript error, but do not capture error such as 404 file not found.

Comment: Welcome, I doubt it wont.

Comment: I believe you want to override `window.onerror` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror